# accessing inner dictionaries (dictionary of dictionaries) with one entry, when not knowing what key or value for that entry are

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2

This is how I declared my dictionary:

```
var dataDictionary: [NSIndexPath:[Int:Bool]]!
```

The inner dictionary will always have **just one entry e.g. [1:true]**. When I search `dataDictionary` I specify a NSIndexPath. The inner dictionary gets returned. Sth like this:

```
var innerDictionary = dataDictionary[indexPath] // is of type [Int:Bool]
```

I would like to access inner dictionarys key and value, but I don't want to specify an Integer or Bool, because it is unknown. I only want to get that Int and/or Bool value stored in inner dictionary. No search of inner dictionary is needed, because if will always contains just one entry. Maybe something like this:

```
var key = innerDictionary.key
var value = innerDictionary.value
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dictionary has only one entry, and you don't know the key, with Swift 2 you can get the first element of the `keys` sequence safely with `if let`:

```
let innerDictionary = [42: true]

if let k = innerDictionary.keys.first {
    print(k)  // prints 42
} else {
    // dict is empty
}
```

Same for the value:

```
if let v = innerDictionary.values.first {
    print(v)  // prints true
} else {
    // key has no value
}
```

Comment: beautiful. you gotta love swift

Answer (score 1):

Try by this way:

```
 func nestedDic(){
 var innerDictionary:NSDictionary = ["Item 1": "data 0", "Item 2": "data 1"]
    //NSLog("original object:\(innerDictionary)")
    NSLog("all keys array:\(innerDictionary.allKeys)")

    if(innerDictionary.isKindOfClass(NSDictionary)){
        for key  in innerDictionary.allKeys{
            let value = innerDictionary.valueForKey(key as! NSString as String)
            NSLog("key value = \(value as! String)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple struct for the inner dictionary if there is only one entry, then you are able to use your favorite property names.

```
struct InnerDictionary {
  var key = 0
  var value = false
}

let indexPath = NSIndexPath(index: 1)
var dataDictionary = [indexPath: InnerDictionary(key: 1, value: true)]

if let innerDictionary = dataDictionary[indexPath] {
  var key = innerDictionary.key
  var value = innerDictionary.value
}
```